# Single Button Placement

Tags: usability, actions

A simple dilemma but one that I would appreciate your views on.  I have a page title and near to it I would like to place the key and ONLY action that a user would need to take.

I have mocked up three options below.  I *think* option 2 represents the best usability but option 3 with a simple icon and tool-tip is a cleaner design and would it be acceptable.

[image]

Your thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this mobile friendly? If so, the third option is NOT usable.

Comment: Also... Add what..? A page title?

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with all three designs.

First you have to know that the last option will not work with mobile since there is no hover with fingers.

Also the label itself doesn't describe the action. What're you adding? A page title? A page? More text?

When ever you're designing actions, make sure the CTA (call to action) has enough description to allow the affordance for what's to come.

Always keep in mind with mobile first interactions (if that's something you're doing... Responsive work). Hovering isn't a mobile friendly interaction.